# Unable to find files in hadoop streaming

Tags: hadoop-streaming

I have a similar issue to [Hadoop Streaming - Unable to find file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339788/hadoop-streaming-unable-to-find-file-error) .   However none of the solutions presented there are working.

My command line is:

```
hadoop jar /mnt/shared/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar -input /user/cloudera/mz_paf/batch_sk=1234 \
-output /user/cloudera/mz_paf/out \
-file /mnt/shared/java/paf-rules.properties -file /mnt/shared/java/pafvalid.py  \
-mapper "pafvalid.py paf-rules.properties 10"
```

This results in

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pafvalid.py": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
```

I have tried several other approaches also mentioned in that other SOF issue including using HDFS locations for the input files: still same error of file not found.  Also have tried just having the files be in the local directory to avoid the path issues. Still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

I have not passed in the argument directly into the command line using hadoop streaming. If I were you, I will try to put that arguments inside the Python script first.

then change the command line here

```
-mapper "pafvalid.py paf-rules.properties 10"
```

To

```
-mapper /mnt/shared/java/pafvalid.py
```

Correct me if you figure that out

Comment: Have you tried this yourself?   What about the issue with the properties file: it needs to be made available to all of the mapper machines.  That is why I put the -files.

Comment: @javadba sorry javadba, I have not tried myself.. just food for thought. You can set up a Network shared file system to across the cluster and put your properties file there.

Comment: Hi, we do not have any NFS (for security reasons beyond scope here..) - all files must be made available in HDFS.