# Opening files on HDFS from Hadoop mapreduce job

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

Usually, I can open a new file with something like this:

```
aDict = {}
with open('WordLists/positive_words.txt', 'r') as f:
    aDict['positive'] = {line.strip() for line in f}

with open('WordLists/negative_words.txt', 'r') as f:
    aDict['negative'] = {line.strip() for line in f}
```

This will open up the two relevant text files in the WordLists folder and append each line to the dictionary as either positive or negative.

When I want to run a mapreduce job within Hadoop however, I don't think this works. I am running my program like so:

```
./hadoop/bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.1.2.jar -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 -file hadoop_map.py -mapper hadoop_reduce.py -input /toBeProcessed -output /Completed
```

I have tried to change the code to this:

```
with open('/mapreduce/WordLists/negative_words.txt', 'r')
```

where mapreduce is a folder on the HDFS, with WordLists a subfolder containing negative words. But my program doesn't find this. Is what I'm doing possible and if so, what is the correct way to load files on the HDFS.

**Edit**

I've now tried:

```
with open('hdfs://localhost:9000/mapreduce/WordLists/negative_words.txt', 'r')
```

This seems to do something, but now I get this sort of output:

```
13/08/27 21:18:50 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
13/08/27 21:18:50 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 50%  reduce 0%
13/08/27 21:18:50 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
```

Then a job fail. So still not right. Any ideas?

**Edit 2:**

Having re-read the API, I notice I can use the `-files` option in the terminal to specify files. The API states:

> The -files option creates a symlink in the current working directory
>   of the tasks that points to the local copy of the file.
>
> In this example, Hadoop automatically creates a symlink named
>   testfile.txt in the current working directory of the tasks. This
>   symlink points to the local copy of testfile.txt.

```
-files hdfs://host:fs_port/user/testfile.txt
```

Therefore, I run:

```
./hadoop/bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.1.2.jar -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 -files hdfs://localhost:54310/mapreduce/SentimentWordLists/positive_words.txt#positive_words -files hdfs://localhost:54310/mapreduce/SentimentWordLists/negative_words.txt#negative_words -file hadoop_map.py -mapper hadoop_map.py -input /toBeProcessed -output /Completed
```

From my understanding of the API, this creates symlinks so I can use "positive_words" and "negative_words" in my code, like this:

```
with open('negative_words.txt', 'r')
```

However, this *still* doesn't work. Any help anyone can offer would be hugely appreciated as I can't do much until I solve this.

**Edit 3:**

I can use this command:

```
-file ~/Twitter/SentimentWordLists/positive_words.txt
```

along with the rest of my command to run the Hadoop job. This finds the file on my local system rather than HDFS. This *doesn't* throw any errors, so it's accepted somewhere as a file. However, I've no idea how to *access* the file.

Comment: Maybe `with open('negative_words', 'r')` ?

Comment: Unfortunately not - still complains

Comment: Try `-files hdfs://localhost:54310/mapreduce/SentimentWordLists/positive_words.txt#positive_words,hdfs://localhost:54310/mapreduce/SentimentWordLists/negative_words.txt#negative_words`

Comment: Tried that one too. I've deleted all code within the mapper class that touches those files to see if the actual import is even working - it isn't! That just brings up the same streaming command error

Comment: Tried both (my comments) together?

Comment: Yeah, but if I omit the first one and JUST use the -files part to import the files, an error occurs - meaning there's no point trying to open the files within the mapper class yet as they're not even being properly imported so are unreachable.

Comment: a) What does log say? (if any)   b) Shouldn't be command line `-mapper hadoop_map.py` ?

Comment: Whoops that was a typo by me. It is hadoop_map. Log just says: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1

Comment: I've added another edit to show where I'm at now!

Comment: Sending with `-file` will put the file in the task's working directory. Try with the first answers of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339788/hadoop-streaming-unable-to-find-file-error

Comment: Does your configuration have: `<property><name>mapred.create.symlink</name><value>yes</value></property>`?. You can check for created symlinks in `logs/userlogs/.../syslog`

Comment: I don't have your last comment, but I don't need it. You're a star! Following the first answer in that other link, of using this: sys.path.append('.'), meant that I could use: with open('positive_words.txt', 'r') as f:
 sentimentDict['positive'] = {line.strip() for line in f}

Comment: So everything's working perfectly. Thank you so much for your time and effort! If you want, feel free to add this as an answer and I'll gladly accept :)

Comment: Thank you! I learn new details too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution after plenty comments :)

Reading a data file in python: send it with `-file` and add to your script the following:

```
import sys
```

Sometimes is needed to add after the `import`:

```
sys.path.append('.')
```

(related to @DrDee comment in [Hadoop Streaming - Unable to find file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339788/hadoop-streaming-unable-to-find-file-error))

Comment: Thanks a lot! appending on path wasn't necessary though!

Answer (score 1):

when dealing with HDFS programatically you should look into FileSystem, FileStatus, and Path. These are hadoop API classes which allow you to access HDFS within your program.

Comment: They are all Java API - I'm using Python.